# Dock ArcGIS 9.3 table of contents

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table-of-contents

[image: undocked TOC]

How do I dock the table of contents within the ArcGIS window.

Comment: Other than writing some VBA code to do that, a quick solution could be to rotate your screen 90 degrees, and hope that the TOC will fit. (alternatively, increase your monitors resolution, or temporarily attach a bigger monitor). In ArcGIS 10, the locations of dockable panes are stored in the registry. If version 9 uses the same logic, you could try to rename HKCU\Software\ESRI\Desktop**.*\ArcMap\DockingPaneLayouts\panestate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dock TOC (Table of contents) you must double click here

[image]

Comment: Table of content tab is not visible. Its out of range of the window screen. is there any way to place the table of content using command.

Comment: Windows => Table of Content